# No suitable method found for collect/reduce - Can't sum a list of Integers with stream()

Tags: java, list, filter, sum, java-stream

In the input, I have a list of Integers and Strings together.

The first stream works fine, the second stream works until the filter, I don't know why. My code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MixedSum {

    public int sum(List<?> mixed) {

        int m = mixed.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof String).map(x -> Integer.parseInt((String) x)).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
        int n = mixed.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof Integer).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));

        return m + n;
    }
}
```

I have this error:

> error: no suitable method found for collect(Collector<Integer,CAP#1,Integer>)
> int n = mixed.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof Integer).collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
> ^
> method Stream.<R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super CAP#2>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) R#1
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
> method Stream.<R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super CAP#2,A,R#2>) is not applicable
> (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
> inferred: CAP#2
> upper bound(s): Integer,Object)
> where R#1,T,R#2,A are type-variables:
> R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>collect(Supplier<R#1>,BiConsumer<R#1,? super T>,BiConsumer<R#1,R#1>)
> T extends Object declared in interface Stream
> R#2 extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R#2>)
> A extends Object declared in method <R#2,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R#2>)
> where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
> CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
> CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
> 1 error

Comment: The first line works fine because there is a cast, and the `parseInt` returns `int` which gets boxed to `Integer`. Therefore, the result of the `map` call is a `Stream<Integer>`. In the second line you only filter, so `collect` is called on a `Stream<?>`. The answers show how to fix that. The one from Alexander Ivanchenko is better because it uses `mapToInt`, which returns an `IntStream` which has a direct `sum` method. It also prevents unnecessary boxing, which can create a lot of `Integer` objects if you have a lot of numbers greater than 127.

Comment: I understand what is being done here, but..... if you have a requirement where a collection of values need to be added together, shouldn't you design the data structure to be composed **strictly** of numeric values to begin with? In my opinion, the requested solution is a code smell. The correct solution is to change the type of the collection to be a list of numbers. The conversion from `String` to `Number` should be done upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before applying the method reference `Integer::intValue` in the second stream you have to **cast** the elements of the stream to the `Integer` type.

Since you want to get just a sum of integer primitives there is no need to resort to the help of collectors, instead, you can coerce a stream of objects to `IntStream` and apply the `sum()` method.

```
        int m = mixed.stream()
                .filter(x -> x instanceof String)
                .mapToInt(x -> Integer.parseInt((String) x))
                .sum();
        
        int n = mixed.stream()
                .filter(x -> x instanceof Integer)
                .mapToInt(x -> (Integer) x)
                .sum();
```

There's no need to do iteration twice, and because in the source list you except only `Integer` and `String` types filter can be discarded. So your method eventually boils down to a couple of lines:

```
    public int sum(List<?> mixed) {
        return mixed.stream()
                .mapToInt(x -> x instanceof Integer? (Integer) x : Integer.parseInt((String) x))
                .sum();
    }
```

**Note:**

- Because `Integer.parseInt()` might cause `NumberFormatException` if conversion fails the stream will not produce the value if the source list contains at least one *string* that is comprised of other symbols apart from digits. That's what is called a *fail-fast implementation* and it makes sense if your intention was not to return a value in case of invalid data but to *emphasize it with an exception*.
- Another thing worth to point out is that this code has value only as *an exercise*. In some languages, you might encounter union types (`String | Number`) and runtime checks using `instanceof` but *Java* cares about *type-safety* and in the real-life scenario you shouldn't create such a mixed collection in the first place. It was probably done using a row-type collection or `Object` class as a generic type in order to *circumvent the compiler*. Instead, it would be cleaner and less error-prone to process the source of string values separately like that:

```
   strSource.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a consequence `sum()` method will be exempted from the redundant responsibility and contracts to:

```
   list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't infer the type. You need to cast it like you do it in your first step:

```
int n = mixed.stream()
             .filter(x -> x instanceof Integer)
             .map(x -> (int) x)
             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

or if you want to use method reference

```
int n = mixed.stream()
             .filter(x -> x instanceof Integer)
             .map(Integer.class::cast)
             .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
```